# Embedd existing ML model in apache flink

Tags: python, machine-learning, apache-flink, flinkml

we are training machine learning models offline and persist them in python pickle-files.

We were wondering about the best way to embedd those pickeled-models into a stream (e.g. sensorInputStream > PredictionJob > OutputStream.

Apache Flink ML seems to be the right choice to train a model with stream-data but not to reference an existing model.

Thanks for you response.

Kind Regards 
Lomungo

Comment: potential workaround: I guess we could use flink asyncio (https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/stream/asyncio.html) to send requests from the stream to a ml-api (e.g. flask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possible solutions depending on the model You are using:

1. Possibly the simples idea is to create external service that will call the model and return the results and then simply call the service with `AsyncFunction`
2. Use some library, again depending on Your model to load the pre-trained model inside a `ProcessFunction`'s `open` method. And then simply calling the model for each data that arrived.

The second solution has two disadvantages, first You need to have the Java version of the specific library available and the other is that You need to somehow externalize the metadata of the model if You want to be able to update it over time.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

To answer your question - there are several models: LinearReg to more complex ones. 

For (2) are you thinking about something like JEP (https://github.com/ninia/jep)? 

I understand the disadvantes you pointed out, isn't (1) handling everything in the job itself most likely more performant?

Comment: Yes, you are right. If You will have the model embedded directly in the job itself, then it will certainly faster, since You don't have the additional latency introduced by waiting for the external service. How much faster it will be, this depends on the setup and where are the job and service localized. I didn't really mean embedding the whole python in Java. For example, You have the Tensorflow library available for Java too, so You can easily train Your model in Python, save the weights, add them to Your Flink project as a resource for example and then simply read them using Java Tensorflow

Comment: I think 1 and 2 are both good opportunities. Thanks a lot - I'll set this to solved.

Comment: https://github.com/FlinkML/flink-jpmml is sometimes used as a way to load pre-trained models into Flink operators.