# Using a pre-trained ML model in Apache Flink

Tags: python, apache-flink, flink-streaming, pmml, flinkml

I am new to Flink and am trying to use a pre-trained classifier in Flink to detect Hate Speech on Twitter. I have an SVM classifier that I trained on Python, but I have no idea how to use it in the Flink code.

One of the [posts here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59563265/embedd-existing-ml-model-in-apache-flink) talks about Async operations, but it goes way over my head. I have also tried using PMML but am facing an issue that I have detailed in a separate [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73401502/how-to-resolve-out-of-memory-issue-when-running-sklearn2pmml).

Are there other methods or simple examples that can help me resolve this doubt?

P.S I am using Flink in Java (not PyFlink).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implemented a solution to this problem by creating a REST API using Flask and setting up a POST method which calls the pre-trained model.

[image]

The server exposes the model to clients.

[image]

In the Flink end, I added a map function which acts as a client, sends the input as a JSON through the post method to my server, and receives the response, I.e. the prediction.

[image]

Worked splendidly!

Answer (score 1):

You can check [Stateful Functions](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-statefun-docs-stable/) which provides a connection between Python and Java.

I think the documentation is not clear enough, you can check [this thread](https://www.mail-archive.com/user@flink.apache.org/msg41350.html) as well.

Comment: Thanks for that! Could have used that, but I found an easier way that aligned with my knowledge of microservices.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer the micro-service approach, you can implement it similarly to the Flask example above, but more efficiently by using Flink's Async IO operator:

https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/operators/asyncio/

This way you're not blocking your pipeline waiting for the HTTP call to return.